# WPF verify call not made from GUI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

I've tried various methods from other SO questions over the last week and this is the best approach I found yet, but I do not know how to unit test this with NUnit.

```
private void VerifyDispatcherThread()
    {
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        if (context != null && context is DispatcherSynchronizationContext)
        {
            Log.For(this).Info("WARNING! - Method Should Not Be Called From Dispatcher Thread.");

            if (DispatcherThreadSafetyEnabled)
            {
                throw new ThreadStateException("Method Should Not Be Called From Dispatcher Thread.");
            }
        }
    }
```

HERE IS OUR TEST (Not Working)

```
        [Test]
        public void Should_throw_exception_when_called_from_dispatcher()
        {
            // Arrange
            var called = false;
            Boolean? success = null;

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(HttpTimeOut);

            // This emulates WPF dispatcher thread
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext());

            Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            // Act
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                try
                {
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DispatcherThreadSafetyEnabled", "true");
                    httpClient.Post("http://Foo", "content xml");
                    success = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    success = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("DispatcherThreadSafetyEnabled", "false");
                }
                called = true;
            });

            // this part is a bit ugly
            // spinlock for a bit to give the other thread a chance
            var timeout = 0;
            while (!called && timeout++ < 1000)
                Thread.Sleep(1);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(success, "Method was never invoked");
            Assert.IsFalse(success.Value, "Expected to fail");
        }
```

DispatcherThreadSafetyEnabled is a app.config setting we have so we can toggle only logging or throwing exceptions.

What we are trying to do is verify the calling method isn't using the GUI thread when invoked. It appears to be working but we are having a hard time trying to unit test this.

Here's hoping someone has done this and can help us out with our challenge.

Comment: If you don't have any other code and you are just checking if it is not null and of type `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`, then can you not simply do `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));` from your Unit Test before calling this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *current* `SynchronizationContext` is set to different implementations by different frameworks (Winforms, WPF, etc).

Quoting from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) MSDN article:

> WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (System.Windows.Forms.dll:
>   System.Windows.Forms) Windows Forms apps will create and install a
>   WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext as the current context for any
>   thread that creates UI controls.
>
> DispatcherSynchronizationContext (WindowsBase.dll:
>   System.Windows.Threading) WPF and Silverlight applications use a
>   DispatcherSynchronizationContext, which queues delegates to the UI
>   thread’s Dispatcher with “Normal” priority. This
>   SynchronizationContext is installed as the current context when a
>   thread begins its Dispatcher loop by calling Dispatcher.Run.

Since you are only testing for not null and the type of the `SynchronizationContext`, try setting current `SynchronizationContext` to an instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`by calling `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext` from your unit tests. Sample code below:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
```

Please note this is not a recommended in a Winforms/WPF application though.

Comment: Is there a recommended way?

Comment: Did setting the SynchronizationContext via SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext in your UnitTest not work?

Comment: No the above test expected success to be true but it was false.

Comment: Your test method not calling `VerifyDispatcherThread` mehtod, or is it being called from httpClient.Post? Also, you won't get WPF dispatcher with Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher in a non-WPF app.

Comment: VerifyDispatcherThread is inside the httpClient.Post method.It is a WPF app, but the Unit Test project is a class library so I am guessing in that case we can't test it?

Comment: Try one last thing, change             `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext());`
 to             `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));`

Comment: Yes, inside the test method.